# Query Studio Issue: Getting Email Addresses of All Auto Suppression List Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, sql-studio

I am trying to get the email addresses of all subscribers of a specific Auto Suppression list. However, the issue is that the name of the column containing email addresses has a space i.e "Email Address". I tried the below query with no luck:

```sql
SELECT [Email Address] as Email
FROM LIST_NAME
```

I get the error: **Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near '('.**

To test my hypothesis that using square brackets to select a column containing a space was causing the issue, I added a new column to the auto suppression list called "Test" and was able to successfully query the list with the below query:

```sql
SELECT Test
from LIST_NAME
```

However, when I attempted this query:

```sql
SELECT [Test]
from LIST_NAME
```

I got the same error message as above (**Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near '('.**)

But, when I put the square brackets around the list name and NOT around column name in the SELECT clause:

```sql
SELECT Test
from [LIST_NAME]
```

the query worked fine.

So it must be something to do with using square brackets around column names in the SELECT clause? If this is true, how do you handle spaces in column names?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try double quote around it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names/2901499#2901499

Comment: @Gortonington It works for "Test" but when I try "Email Address" I get "Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near 'Address'."

Comment: I've already faced the exact same problem with Query Studio. Finally, I ended up creating a query activity and runing it in Automation Studio. It worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried single quotation marks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Query Studio seems to run into this issue when you do not use an alias for the table.

Try this:

```
SELECT l.[Email Address] as Email
FROM LIST_NAME l
```

Comment: Works! Marked as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I always get the same error when the first field in the `select` statement have square brackets, this is some issue with Query Studio. Get another field as the first field, and just ignore it, or "set a dummy" field as the first one:

```
Select
  'ignore' as dummy,
   [Email Address] as Email
FROM LIST_NAME
```